# Calculation of percentile and mean

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to find the 3% percentile of the following data and then average the data.
Given below is the data structure.

0                    NaN
1                    NaN
2                    NaN
3                    NaN
4                    NaN
...                  ...
96927                NaN
96928                NaN
96929                NaN
96930                NaN
96931                NaN

Over here the concerned data lies exactly between the data from 13240:61156.
Given below is my code:

```
enter code here
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
load_var=pd.read_excel(r'path\file name.xlsx')
load_var
a=pd.DataFrame(load_var['column whose percentile is to be found'])
print(a)
b=np.nanpercentile(a,3)
print(b)
```

Please suggest the changes in the code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) with `mean` in [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'col':[7,8,9,4,2,3, np.nan],
})

f = lambda x: x.quantile(0.03)
f.__name__ = 'q'
s = df['col'].agg(['mean', f])
print (s)
mean    5.50
q       2.15
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: sorry, coludn't understand.

Comment: @chinu - What not understand?

Comment: 1]I am not familiar with the lambda function.2] I tried the same thing in excel i am getting only a single value of percentile, where as what I wanted was that to do ascending of all the data values and select those values which are of 3 percentile and then take the mean of it.

Comment: @chinu - Ok, so what is expected output from `[7,8,9,4,2,3, np.nan]` ?

Comment: its just the single value 1.682511. I guess you have misunderstood the data.

Comment: 209.088913
206.636444
200.276352
193.894272
193.293747
192.889603
188.6689
188.282303
188.272278
187.062531
186.344467
186.196503
182.578705
179.415924
179.214279
176.40036
176.295074
173.558746
171.633377
171.187286
170.009079
169.883072
                                                                                                                                   its like this and around 50,000 numbers in total

Comment: so I want all this data arranged in the ascending order and select the data of 3% percentile and then calculate the mean of it

Comment: @chinu - How is count `1.682511` from `[7,8,9,4,2,3, np.nan]` ? If 3% percentile is `2.15` ?